# Проверка наличия элемента в таблице sqlite и дописывание значения в ячейку без стирания предыдущего значения на python и sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

Я получаю id и строку.

1. Я должен проверить, есть ли этот id в столбике(userid) и если есть, то дописать в ячейку соседнего столбика(grade), без стирания существующего значения ячейки.
2. Я должен проверить, есть ли этот id в столбике(userid) и если есть,то стереть значение ячейки в соседнем столбике (grade) и написать туда новое значение

Comment: долг дело серьезное, проблема то собсна в чем?

Comment: Я хз как сделать допись значения в ячейку

Comment: `UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE ...`?

Comment: Ай. Я про UPDATE забыл. Спасибо

Comment: выложу как ответ чтоле

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проверить можно банально получив и распарсив значения из таблицы:

`SELECT * ... WHERE ...`

а изменить(обновить) значение можно так:

`UPDATE ... SET value, .. WHERE ...`

Comment: Обновить то так, а как добавить я хз....

Comment: А понял. Можно просто захватить значение, их объединить и UPDATE-ом запихнуть